# How to stop Light Table stripping spaces at the end of a line?

Tags: text-editors

I'm using [Light Table](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable) to write a README.md file. I need to add two spaces to the end of a line of text but when I save the document, Light Table seems to remove those two spaces.

How can I stop Light Table stripping spaces at the end of a line?

**Update:** I noticed a line in the [default.behaviors](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/blob/master/deploy/settings/default/default.behaviors#L223) file.

```
[:editor.file-backed :lt.objs.editor.file/remove-trailing-whitespace]
```

Is that something that can be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally, in my experience, editors can usually use a hard or non-breaking space and this is accessed as Ctrl-space or shift-space, or alt-space or ctrl-alt-space.  I don't know light-table itself, but there is usually a way.  Can you insert symbols? A hard space is often available at high character numbers.    Or if you're using a PC, try the high codes (hold left-Alt and type a high number character on the number pad (use number lock!))  ╠ and ☺ are characters I got with alt-204 and alt-1 and so on. 
you may find that the Alt buttons are not always identical and nor are ctrl or shift, that is, the left ctrl and the right ctrl sometimes give different results.
Sorry to be vague, but I hope this helps a little.

Comment: Hi Neil B, thanks for the tips. I'm able to insert the line break in the editor, my problem is markdown format. I need 2 blank spaces to remain at the end of a particular line of text. Markdown interprets this as a line break. Then when I share my file (upload to GitHub for example) the line break will be enforced when the document is displayed. Light Table is removing these spaces which isn't the behaviour I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, henry asked the same question on Github and here is the answer:

> To disable just add the following to your user behaviors:
>   [:editor.file-backed :-lt.objs.editor.file/remove-trailing-whitespace]
>
> or if you like you can target different editor types like
>   [:editor.markdown :-lt.objs.editor.file/remove-trailing-whitespace]

https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/2171

I wanted to share the solution because I faced the same problem today and I had some difficulties to get my answer.